# php using humanTiming function to find the time until an event starts

Tags: php, datetime

I am using this function

```
function humanTiming ($time)
{
    $time = $time - time() ; // to get the time since that moment
    $time = ($time<1)? 1 : $time;
    $tokens = array (
    31536000 => 'year',
    2592000 => 'month',
    604800 => 'week',
    86400 => 'day',
    3600 => 'hour',
    60 => 'minute',
    1 => 'second',
    );

    foreach ($tokens as $unit => $text) 
    {
        if ($time < $unit) continue;
            $numberOfUnits = floor($time / $unit);
            return $numberOfUnits.' '.$text.(($numberOfUnits>1)?'s':'');
    }
}
```

which is a slightly modified version of the original as i swapped these to around $time - time() so that the function would give me a result which would tell me a time until a specific date is not a time when a specific date was.

what i am trying to do is when the time is less than 1 second have it display "expired" instead of the current default "1 second"

any ideas how i can do this?
Many thanks

Luke

Comment: See [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/), it will make your life easier.

Comment: what is human timing function ?

Comment: `$time = ($time<1)? 1 : $time;` replace with `if ($time < 1) { return 'expired';}`

Comment: thanks @cske that worked a treat!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$time = ($time<1)? 1 : $time;
```

replace with

```
if ($time < 1) { return 'expired';}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it before the loop:

```
function humanTiming ($time)
    {
        $time = $time - time() ; // to get the time since that moment
        $time = ($time<1)? 1 : $time;
        $tokens = array (
        31536000 => 'year',
        2592000 => 'month',
        604800 => 'week',
        86400 => 'day',
        3600 => 'hour',
        60 => 'minute',
        1 => 'second',
        );

        if($time < 1 ) return 'expired';

        foreach ($tokens as $unit => $text) 
        {
            if ($time < $unit) continue;
                $numberOfUnits = floor($time / $unit);
                return $numberOfUnits.' '.$text.(($numberOfUnits>1)?'s':'');
        }
    }
```